# Clever way to check if value meets threshold in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Disclaimer: Numbers below are randomly generated

What I'm trying to do is, purely in VBA, look at the ratio of [column B]/[column A] and checking whether or not the ratio in row 10 (=1,241/468) is below the minimum of the ratios or above the maximum of the ratios in rows 1 through 9 **but only** compared to the rows where there is a 1 in column C.

That is, compare Cell(B10)/Cell(A10) to Cell(B2)/Cell(A2), Cell(B3)/Cell(A3), etc. (only comparing against rows with a 1 in column C).

The workbook I'm working with has a lot more data and columns and I'm not allowed to explicitly edit the cells, so defining a new column is out of the question. Is there a way to do this in VBA such that it essentially returns a boolean depending whether or not the ratio in the last row violates the threshold defined above?

[image]

Comment: Interesting problem -- what have you tried?

Comment: The only way I've approached is by brute force (looping down each row; check if the value in column C is 1; compare the ratio to the max/min and if it's above/below, then that's the new max/min; until I get to the last row and check if the ratio in the last row violates the threshold or not). Wanted to see if anyone had a better way to do this like employing some Excel functions in the VBA that I may not have been aware of.

Comment: That is fairly natural. If speed is an issue, why don't you post your code? There might be some simple optimizations that could speed it up. There are worksheet functions like `Min` and `Max` that can be used in VBA but to use them in that way you would need to place the value in a VBA array, in which case you might as well calculate them in the process.

Comment: Perhaps you can do a User Defined Function with the Range input as those above. The UDF will do all the calc and conditions work. The reason to have the range as input is that if the range are changed, then the UDF will execute again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the minimum and maximum ratios (with criteria) easily with the [AGGREGATE¹ function's](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) [SMALL sub-function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) and [LARGE sub-function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db).

[image: Minimum Maximum Ratios with criteria]

The formulas in D13:E13 are,

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, ((B1:B9)/(A1:A9))/C1:C9, 1)
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, ((B1:B9)/(A1:A9))/C1:C9, 1)
```

The **6** is the AGGREGATE parameter for ignoring error values. By dividing the ratio
by the value in column C we are producing `#DIV/0!` errors for anything we do not want considered leaving them ignored. If the values in C were more diverse, we could divide by (C1:C9=1) to produce the same results.

Since we are using the SMALL and LARGE sub-functions, we can easily retrieve the second, third, etc. ratios by increasing the *k* parameter (the **1** off the back end).

I've modified some of the values in your sample slightly to demonstrate that the min and max with criteria are being picked up correctly.

These can be adapted to VBA with the [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) or [Application.Evaluate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx).

¹<sub>The [AGGREGATE¹ function's](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in previous versions.</sub>